# SBT class from the classpath not found

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am having a weird issue with a basic sbt project (created with scala/hello-world.g8): the classes from the classpath are showing as "not found" by an IDE (on the screenshot below it is Eclipse Oxygen.3, but I have also had the same issue in [IDEA IntelliJ UE 2017.3.5](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13605)). The class that I need is there and was added via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, however the IDE complains:

[image]

And it is not only the IDEs, if I try to run `sbt compile` compile fails for the lack of this same class. For eclipse I did add `sbteclipse-plugin` and run `sbt eclipse` as expected. I would appreciate if anyone could give me a hand with this as I am blocked with this issue.

Comment: Please note, that the **value** WeightedQUByHeight not found, not class. You have not provided enough information (at least the definition of WeightedQUByHeight), but here you are calling `WeightedQUByHeight.apply(size)`. In case of **case class**, the _companion object_ is created automatically that has the `apply` method creating its instances, but for regular class the companion object implementation is up to you. So, short answer: if the class you try to create is not a **case class**, create it with `new`, unless explicitly designed otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, Anatoly. That is embarrassing :-) Shame, shame on me. For previous exercise I had a factory method which returned one of the case classes, but I didn't mark WeightedQUByHeight with **case** That solved this case. I am going to withdraw my ridiculous post from intellij idea support site now. Thanks once again.